# Change SliderThumbStyle value from Slider definition

Tags: wpf, slider, styles, string.format

I have this `SliderThumbStyle`:

```
<Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="outerBorder"
                                Background="{DynamicResource ApplicationBorderBrush}"
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ApplicationBorderBrush}"
                                Height="24"
                                Width="24"
                                Opacity="1" 
                                BorderThickness="2"
                                CornerRadius="10"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="sliderValue"
                                   FontSize="10"
                                   Foreground="Silver"
                                   Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Slider}, StringFormat={}{0:N1}}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In my application i am using this Slider `Style` twice but one of them not needed this `N1` `StringFormat` but `N0`for only integer values.

Any idea how to choose this when i define my `Slider` in advanced ?

As `mm8` suggestive i try this:

```
<Slider Tag="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, StringFormat=N1}" />
```

Style:

```
Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Slider}}"/>
```

But it seems that it now show the value in `N1` format but `1.23456789`

I also try this:

```
Tag="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, StringFormat={}{0:N1}}"
```

Comment: The data is the same, maybe i can do that inside value_changed event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you can't change the `StringFormat` without modifying the `Style`. What you could do is to bind to the `Tag` property of the `Slider` in your `Style`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="sliderValue"
            FontSize="10"
            Foreground="Silver"
            Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Slider}}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

...and then handle the `ValueChanged` event of each individual `Slider` and set the `Tag` property to a formatted `string`:

```
private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    Slider slider = (Slider)sender;
    slider.Tag = slider.Value.ToString("N1");
}
```

You may want to wrap this functionality an attached behaviour:

```
public class SliderFormatBehavior
{
    public static string GetStringFormat(Slider treeViewItem)
    {
        return (string)treeViewItem.GetValue(StringFormatProperty);
    }

    public static void SetStringFormat(Slider slider, string value)
    {
        slider.SetValue(StringFormatProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StringFormatProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "StringFormat",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(SliderFormatBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnStringFormatChanged));

    static void OnStringFormatChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Slider slider = depObj as Slider;
        if (slider != null)
        {
            if (slider.IsLoaded)
            {
                SetTag(slider);
            }
            else
            {
                slider.Loaded += Slider_Loaded;
            }
            slider.ValueChanged += Slider_ValueChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void Slider_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Slider slider = (Slider)sender;
        SetTag(slider);
        slider.Loaded -= Slider_Loaded;
    }

    private static void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        SetTag((Slider)sender);
    }

    private static void SetTag(Slider slider)
    {
        slider.Tag = slider.Value.ToString(GetStringFormat(slider));
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
<Slider ... local:SliderFormatBehavior.StringFormat="N1" />
```

Comment: Thats great, i also can on the way change the text ? for example "Speed: 1.0"

Comment: Please see my update, there is problem with the format

Comment: You will have to implement the `ValueChanged` event programmatically then. See my edit.

Comment: Ok that works for me, can i also Add text before this value ?

Comment: Yes, just set the Tag property to any string you want.

Comment: Where exactly ?

Comment: In the event handler; `slider.Tag = "Speed: " + slider.Value.ToString("N1");`

Comment: Yes thats works but the only thing is when the application startup, so i can see only the value and only after i moved the slider only then i can see the text before

Comment: Also set the `Tag` property in the constructor right after `InitializeComponent()` then.

Comment: Where i need to put this local:SliderFormatBehavior.StringFormat="N1"

Comment: Are you using the behaviour or are you handling the ValueChanged event in the code-behind? It's one way or the other but not both.

Comment: Some method is better ?

Comment: BTW how to set the Tag property after InitializeComponent()

Comment: If you don't know that a behaviour is, you should probably stick to the code-behind approach.

Comment: Like this: `slider.Tag = slider.Value.ToString("N1");`

Comment: This not helped, again i can see my text only after the first time i moved the slider

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. What if you focus the Slider?

Comment: I try change Focusable property for true or false and same results

Comment: Your original question has been answered. If you have another issue you should ask a new question. Please don't ask addtional questions in the comments field.

Comment: I try change Focusable property for true or false and same results